# How to automatically name foreign references to something meaningful?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Let's say I have table Customer and two references to table City. In effect (by default) I will get City1 and City2 foreign references for each record of Customer. As you can see when building name EF takes only foreign table name into account, and ignores the source field.

It would be much better if EF could use both -- target table name and source field name, like for field custBorn --> custBornCity, and for field custLives --> custLivesCity.

**QUESTION**

Is there any way to do this **automatically** -- anything more meaningful than just numbered references (City1, City2...)?

## Edits

### 1

I have meaningful field name (in table), meaningful foreign key. But EF ignores those info. It focuses solely on target table name (which is meaningful only if used once).

### 2

I rephrase the question by giving some examples. My foreign keys (in DB) are named FK_Born_City and FK_Lives_City. So I would like to have generated automatically by EF such names:

- FK_Born_City, FK_Lives_City (from foreign keys names) or
- Born_City, LivesCity (from foreign keys names) or
- custBornCity, custLivesCity (concatenation of field + table name) or
- CitycustBorn, CitycustLives (the same as above but reversed order) or
- FK_Born_CitycityBorn, FK_Lives_CitycityLives (concatenation of FK + field names, ugly) or...

  I hope you get the picture.

Comment: 'how to automatically generate meaning', as in 'how to reduce entropy in a system'. I guess you mean: if I decide what is a pseudo-meaningful way to name foreign references, how can I automatically let it happen?

Comment: @Sehe, probably it is my bad English, if you read me as "how to generate meaning".

Comment: @sehe, the question is perfect and it is a big pain for every developer, we did manage to write custom code generator which fixes this problem unfortunately it is too big to fit as answer here. But it is possible to generate meaningful names.

Comment: @Akash Kava, hmm, it seems history repeats again -- I wrote the such generator for LinqToSQL, not it is time to do exactly the same for EF :-(

Comment: I agree, but the easier will be to switch to code first and you can generate your code first code from some xml.

Answer (score 0):

> [...] ignores the source field

Not unless the properties are static. As long as the properties exist on an object instance of type `Customer`, you can't argue that the source part is being ignored, afaict

Comment: Look, I have meaningful field in table, I have a meaningful foreign key, but all those were ignored.

Comment: Aha, we have located the source of meaning you want to use. <strike>If you update the question, let me delete this answer. Perhaps even mention examples of what you consider 'meaningful' database names.</strike> **udpate** I think I have found where you are trying to say that. You can make it more explicit (my fields are named: BORN and LIVES, and I would like to have the generated properties named `BornCity`, `LivesCity` respectively.

Comment: Yes, this or CityBorn, CityLives, I don't care, but this has meaning, quite opposite to City1, City2.

Answer (score 0):

In Sql server 2008, it's automatically use table name and field name while creating FK constraint name.

Sql server ignores the the field value while creating default constraint.

You can create a meaningful name for FK constraints using following sample scripts.

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.foreign_keys WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[FK_TableName_ColumnName]') AND parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[TableName]'))

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TableName]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_TableName_ColumnName] FOREIGN KEY([PK_Field])
REFERENCES [dbo].[TableName2] ([FK_Field])
GO
```